# Maven custom archetype failing to generate project

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to create new maven archetype to generate custom project as per my needs. My project looks like below

[image]

My archetype pom looks like following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tarkshala</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>tarkshala-service-models-archetype</name>

    <!-- Used to point local artifacts to the hosted repo , Starts  -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>maven-releases</name>
            <url>http://maven.tarkshala.com:10081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>maven-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.tarkshala.com:10081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <!--  Ends  -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!--    Check we can delete compiler properties-->
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

and my archetype.xml looks like following

```xml
<archetype-descriptor xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"
                      name="maven-archetype-sample" partial="false">

    <requiredProperties>
        <!-- This is used in pom.xml of the future app. -->
        <requiredProperty key="projectName">
            <defaultValue>TarkshalaService</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>


    <fileSets>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/**.java</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>

        <fileSet filtered="true">
            <directory/>
            <includes>
                <include>*.yml</include>
                <include>.gitignore</include>
                <include>*.md</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>


</archetype-descriptor>
```

mvn clean install is successful when done on archetype, but mvn generate fails as following

```bash
~/W/r/maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models (master|✚1) [1]$ mvn archetype:generate                                  \
                                                                      -DarchetypeGroupId=com.tarkshala                \
                                                                      -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models          \
                                                                      -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT                \
                                                                      -DgroupId=com.tarkshala                                \
                                                                      -DartifactId=dhaba-models \
                                                                      -DprojectName=DhabaModels
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.tarkshala:maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 31, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------< com.tarkshala:maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models >-------
[INFO] Building tarkshala-service-models-archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) @ maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repository with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.892 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-28T07:38:18+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) on project maven-archetype-tarkshala-service-models: Cannot invoke "org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom.getValue()" because the return value of "org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom.getChild(String)" is null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Can someone please help to point what exactly am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved this but maybe it will help someone else. You must rename the your archetype.xml file to archetype-metadata.xml. This is what fixed it for me.

Comment: It is resolved, though I don't know what did I do.